# I'm trying to make an Image Slider but when I set the position of angle left icon to absolute, it disappears

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

The angle left icon basically disappears when I set its position to absolute, but it remains otherwise.[image]

Here the angle left icon is not visible due its position property. How can it appear on the screen so that I can position it on the top left part of the image, so as to make an image slider.

This is my html code:

```
<section>
            <div class="team">
                <div>
                    <h1 id="teamtext">Our Team and Contributers</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="imageslider">
                        <img src="assets/photo1.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo2.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo3.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo4.jpg">
                        <img src="assets/photo5.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slideleft">
                    <i class="uil uil-angle-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="slideright">
                    <i class="uil uil-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
.content{
    height: 400px;
    width: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imageslider{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.imageslider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slideleft{
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.slideright{
    color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

I searched similar questions in the internet but they aren't working.

Comment: It's probably hidden below the image. You should always use the inspect tool(right-click->Inspect) when you feel something is not right.

Comment: I tried using Z index to the property of that particular div so that the div appears over the image but, it doesn't, how can it be displayed over the image? using position relative property the space left by the angle left icon disturbs the whole css layout